# HTML5 datalist - always show unfiltered options

Tags: datalist

I would like to have a textfield input with a datalist of e.g. 10 fixed options.

Instead of the usual autocomplete behavior, I would like the dropdown to always show the complete list.

Especially, if the input has a pre-filled value, and the user clicks, I would like the dropdown to open and show the unfiltered list of options, so the user can use it like a select element.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Can you explain how this would be different from just a <select> element? Did you want pressing the first letter of an option to highlight that option, or something like that?

Comment: unlike a select element, you have a free-text option.

Comment: My particular use case is, you can type a url path, but get the last 10 visited paths (within that site) as dropdown suggestions.